# Spring JdbcTemplate butchUpdate UPDATE org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc

I have started learning Spring MVC a few days ago and now I am trying to do a butchUpdate. I have found an [article](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/) how to do it but I get an exception that is below.I am using HSQLDB in memory database.
Here is my code:

```
public void updateStockBatch(List<Product> allProducts, int addQuantity, int noOfUnits) {
    String SQL = "UPDATE products SET UNITS_IN_STOCK = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        int batchSize = 0;
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            for (Product product : allProducts) {
                if (product.getUnitsInStock() < noOfUnits) {
                    ps.setLong(1, product.getUnitsInStock() + addQuantity);
                    ps.setString(2, product.getProductId());
                    batchSize++;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return batchSize;
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
    Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE products SET UNITS_IN_STOCK = ? WHERE ID = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE products SET UNITS_IN_STOCK = ? WHERE ID = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE products SET UNITS_IN_STOCK =? WHERE ID = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:99)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.InMemoryProductRepository.updateStockBatch(InMemoryProductRepository.java:53)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.ProductProductServiceImpl.updateAllStock(ProductProductServiceImpl.java:30)
    com.packt.webstore.controller.ProductController.updateStock(ProductController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: statement is not in batch mode
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlExceptionSQL(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:966)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.InMemoryProductRepository.updateStockBatch(InMemoryProductRepository.java:53)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.ProductProductServiceImpl.updateAllStock(ProductProductServiceImpl.java:30)
    com.packt.webstore.controller.ProductController.updateStock(ProductController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hsqldb.HsqlException: statement is not in batch mode
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlExceptionSQL(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:966)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.InMemoryProductRepository.updateStockBatch(InMemoryProductRepository.java:53)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.ProductProductServiceImpl.updateAllStock(ProductProductServiceImpl.java:30)
    com.packt.webstore.controller.ProductController.updateStock(ProductController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the way this works. The principle of `batchUpdate()` is to execute the same parameterized SQL query N times.

The BatchPreparedStatementSetter is first called by JdbcTemplate to know the batch size. Suppose it returns 10. JdbcTemplate will then call setValues() 10 times (with 0, then 1, then 2, etc. until 9).

Your code returns 0 as batch size, which doesn't make sense, and its `setValues` method sets the same parameters several times on the same statement, which doesn't make sense either.

A correct implementation would be:

```
public void updateStockBatch(List<Product> allProducts, int addQuantity, int noOfUnits) {
    String sql = "UPDATE products SET UNITS_IN_STOCK = ? WHERE ID = ?";
    List<Product> productsToUpdate = 
        allProducts.stream()
                   .filter(p -> p.getUnitsInStock() < noOfUnits)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!productsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return productsToUpdate.size();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {

                Product product : productsToUpdate.get(i);
                ps.setLong(1, product.getUnitsInStock() + addQuantity);
                ps.setString(2, product.getProductId());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing. It all makes sense now. Thank you.